# Is there a way to look for a cell that does not exist in another table?

Tags: sql, string, contains, string-concatenation

[image: lai]

I am looking for a way to filter out all the "already taken" words inside a list, with the taken words being from another list.

For example:

```
dog,cat,fish 
wolf,elephant

the list:
dog, cat, fish, wolf, elephant, tiger, bird.
```

Now I want to only select "tiger" and "bird".

Notice: Dog,cat,fish is concatenated, and is 1 string inside 1 column of a row.

Comment: If your data was normalized it would be an easy task...

Comment: Sadly i do not know what this means, if you had an example i could try to change my table?

Comment: Storing a comma-separated list of values in a column in a relational database is almost always a sign of a poor database design. Normalizing such a table to first normal form will make working with the table much more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

change your table to hold one item only in a given row: e.g.

```
animal
------------
id
name
```

then fill in values like this:

```
1, 'Fish'
2, 'Bird'
3, 'Dog'
```

etc.

then you need an idea of a 'list' maybe like so:

```
my_list
----------
list_id
animal_id
```

Comment: I get that, but sadly my task doesnt really allow for that. We need to have a random amount of ingredients per recipe, each ingredient has to be in a single column/row, because i do not know how to fill a random amount of columns per row for each recipe.

Comment: Ive added a picture to show how the current table looks like, if you have a better idea to pull a random amount of rows out of a column inside a different table and insert them into this table for further editing